# Is the Weil pairing on elliptic curves a perfect pairing

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve and $m$ be a positive integer such that char$(K)\nmid m$. I know that the Weil pairing defined on elliptic curves is a bilinear & non-degenerate pairing. However is the pairing perfect? Do we have,

$$E[m]\cong \text{Hom}(E[m],\mu_m)$$
If so, how?

Comment: Are you taking $E$ over a field $K$ of characteristic not dividing $m$, and defining "$E[m]$" as the group of $m$-torsion points over the algebraic closure of $K$? Or do you want to take a more high-tech viewpoint involving group schemes? If you take the "obvious" interpretation then there is basically nothing to prove: $E[m]$ and $Hom(E[m], \mu_m)$ are finite groups both of size $m^2$; the Weil pairing gives a map $E[m] \to Hom(E[m], \mu_m)$; "nondegenerate" means that this map is injective; but an injective map between finite sets of the same size is a bijection, qed.

Comment: @David Loeffler Yes I'm assuming char($K)\nmid m$. I should have mentioned it, I'll edit my question. Also, this implies that for a prime $\ell$ different from char$(K)$, the $\ell$-adic Weil pairing on the Tate module of $E$, $T_{\ell}(E)$, is also perfect, right?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed imply that.